# querying self applied parameter in mysql through c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters, mysql-connector

I need to run a query on Mysql DB that retrieve the last 10 rows from a table which have no index column. I succeed to create the query-

```
        SET @row_number:=0;
        select activity from (
            SELECT @row_number:= @row_number+ 1 AS rowNumber, activity 
            FROM activities a ) as myT 
        where  myT.rowNumber > (select count(activity) from activities)- 10
```

But i need to run it through C#. And using MysqlCommand i can't create the parameter @row_number. Using  `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` dosen't help
because the parameter need to be assigned when the query is executing.
(using the `Parameters.AddWithValue` produce the following error = 
"..syntax to use near ':= 1 + 1...").

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a mistake - I don't want to  retrieve the top 10 - I want to retrieve the last 10

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the `LIMIT` clause:

```
select activity from activities 
    LIMIT 10
```

I believe you'll have to create a stored procedure if you want to use a parameter for the `LIMIT` amount.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but if you're only trying to grab the first 10 records why not use this:

SELECT TOP 10 [columnName] FROM [Table]

This returns the top 10 results in the database table.

or in C# you can set a variable

int rowNumber = 0;
then use the command.Parameter.add("@rowNumber", rowNumber);

that might work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to select the last 10 rows.I don't have an id/pk column do i can't do order by

Comment: Op, sorry my bad didnt catch the "last 10" part =p

Comment: May i ask why this table does not have any sort of PK or ID column? such as a SequenceNumber column? It would make quite a bit easier for you.

Comment: This is sort of a test I need to do.To find a way to select the 10 last row with out using a pk/id column